# HTML and Python play nicely with date format

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following code:

```
            {% for x in fixtures %}
                <TR style="display:block" onclick="team_visibility('match{{ forloop.counter }}');">

                    <TD> {{ x.fixturedate }}</TD>
```

There is obviously more to it but I do not think that is relevant for now.  It currently works but it displays a horribly long looking date and time.  Below is an example of the output:

```
29 Oct 2016, 5:30 p.m.
```

Whereas I would like to just return "17:30".  Is this possible within the code or do I have to go back to the drawing board and amend it at the view stage?

Comment: Sorry, I did not expect it to return time.  I just want to know is it possible to convert it on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [`time` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#time):

```
{{ x.fixturedate|time:"H:i" }}
```